# Google charts - setting the right locale to display values in £s

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I've got a chart Google bar chart with currency values and I simply want to have the Y-axis formatted with £s. I've tried to explicitly set the locale using 'en' but it still displays as $. If I set other locales it does then display in the local currency for that locale ... but it doesn't seem to work for English £s.

`google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart'], language: 'en'});`

e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/ynsqwe6o/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use language code --> `'en-GB'`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  language: 'en-GB'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
  data.addColumn('number', 'GDP');
  data.addRows([
    ['US', 16768100],
    ['China', 9181204],
    ['Japan', 4898532],
    ['Germany', 3730261],
    ['France', 2678455]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      left: 108
    },
    title: 'GDP of selected countries, in \u00A3pounds',
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    legend: 'none',
    bar: {
      groupWidth: '95%'
    },
    vAxis: {
      format: "currency",
      gridlines: {
        count: 4
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('number_format_chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="number_format_chart"></div>
```